# how to draw another image within the camera preview of opencv in Android

Tags: android, opencv

Am new to opencv , I would like to do a template matching in Android using opencv, and I would like to load both images to be matched in the opencv camera preview. thanx

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you provide a better explanation of exactly what you're trying to do, what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I'm answering the right question, but:

In general, to have an image covering the camera preview, you do something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/halftransparent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/coveringView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The idea is that the children of FrameView are drawn one on top of another, and if the 2nd one is half-transparent...